# Git push heroku master pushes modifications even with empty commit

Tags: git, heroku

After I merged a remote branch with the master one, I wanted to push to my heroku app one file. I did the following:

> git add path_of_file
>
> git commit -m "message"
>
> git push heroku master

But it pushed some other modifications I was working on. Even if the commit only contained the modified file I added. I did a rollback with heroku:

> heroku rollback

And my modifications disappeared. I still want to push my modified file but each time I push it, the other modifications are also pushed... I even tried to do an empty commit but when I push it, again other modifications are pushed.

When I do `git log heroku/master..HEAD` I only see the file I want to push.

I'm starting with git, any idea how I can push this file without other modifications?

Comment: Git doesn't allow you to push "files". You can only push commits around. Running "git push" brings the remote repository up-to-date with your local repository. That is, any changes you have committed locally will be pushed to the remote repository.

Comment: How can I revert all local commits? Will it be the solution?

Comment: I also had to do a git pull heroku master after removing some local commits, maybe it's the source of the problem?